# How to use Nested While Loop in Incrementing values

Tags: python, while-loop, increment, python-turtle

Im quite confused on how can i can increment a variable in python since ++ operator is not allowed and the objective is to limit the the movement of turtle lib .left and .forward given that the canvas has only a width and height of 150

```
while t:
unif = uniform(-75, 75)  # To move face in every possible angle
forw = randint(-1, 1)  # Move every 1 pixel, -1 for back 1 for forward
t.left(unif)
t.forward(forw)
sleep(0.01)
while countt > 75 or countt < -75:
    print("Outside")
    sys.exit(1)
    while unif > 0 or forw > 0:
        countt = + 1
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to write `count += 1`?

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. 
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
You need to look up how to do auto-increment in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In absence of the ++ operator in Python, you use += 1 to increment by one. Notice that unlike your code, the = sign comes after +. There are other problems with your code that we can't fix since we don't have the whole code and don't know what it's trying to achieve. Below is the general way a while loop is incremented. If you nest multiple while loops inside each other, you need to increment the variables within each loop and/or provide conditional statements to break out of each loop.

```
variable = 0
while variable < 10:
    print("Hi")
    variable += 1
```

Upon request, here is an example of multiple nested loops, including an infinite loop (While True):

```
while True:
    n = 0
    while n < 5:
        print(f'n={n} Hi')
        n += 1

        m = 0
        while m < 3:
            print(f'  m={m} You')
            m +=1

            for k in range(2):
                print(f'    k={k} Bye')

    response = input("Should I keep going? Type n to stop: ")
    if response == "n":
        break
```

Comment: May i know how to implement increment this in a nested while loop